# Digital Ocean Kubernetes secrets certificate connect with Managed Database

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, kubernetes-secrets

I am trying to connect my Kubernetes Cluster in Digital Ocean with a Managed Database.

I need to add the `CA CERTIFICATE` that is a file with extension `cer`.  Is this the right way to add this file/certificate to a secret?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret-db-ca
type: kubernetes.io/tls
data:
  .tls.ca: |
        "<base64 encoded ~/.digitalocean-db.cer>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to create a secret from certificate**

---

The easiest and fastest way is to create a secret from command line:

```
kubectl create secret generic secret-db-ca --from-file=.tls.ca=digitalocean-db.cer
```

Please note that type of this secret is `generic`, not `kubernetes.io/tls` because `tls` one requires both keys provided: `tls.key` and `tls.crt`

Also it's possible to create a key from manifest, however you will need to provide full `base64 encoded` string to the data field and again use the type `Opaque` in manifest (this is the same as generic from command line).

It will look like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret-db-ca
type: Opaque
data:
  .tls.ca: |
     LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJ..........
```

Option you tried to use is used for `docker config` files. Please see [Docker config - secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#docker-config-secrets)

---

**Note!** I tested the above with `cer` certificate.

DER (Distinguished Encoding Rules) is a binary encoding for X.509 certificates and private keys, they do not contain plain text (extensions .cer and .der). Secret was saved in `etcd` (generally speaking database for kubernetes cluster), however there may be issues with workability of secrets based on this type of secrets.

There is a chance that different type/extension of certificate should be used (Digital Ocean has a lot of useful and good documentation).

---

Please refer to [secrets in kubernetes page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/).

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor thank you for your answer, I was able to create the secret and I checked it is working as secret. Now I am facing another issues with the connection, but I am working on it.
Also thanks for the explanation, very helpful.